# C++: how to convert hexidecimal HANDLE to decimal?

Tags: c++, types, type-conversion

In c++, I get an HANDLE type ID from another function, which appears to be a hexidecimal, and I want to convert it to decimal.

```
HANDLE id = getCurrentID();
int decimalID = static_cast<int>( id );
```

But the second line gives out this error:

```
Cannot convert from 'HANDLE' to 'int'.
```

This is the first time I encountered `HANDLE` type. Could someone help and explain? Thank you.

Update:

I am using Windows XP and Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: And you find the definition if you check your includes, which might be nested and many.

Comment: Hexadecimal and decimal aren't properties of a type. Computers store everything in base-2, binary. It's just that on *display*, (hexa)decimal is more compact. But 15 = 0xF = 0b1111.  All the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to guess that you are on `Windows` because `HANDLE` is a name that is usually used by Microsoft's stuff.

The `HANDLE` type is a pointer to an object (of unspecified type), and is passed into other functions to perform operations on that object. In general, there is not a need to manipulate it directly.

I am not sure exactly why you want to convert it to an `int`, because it is not usually useful to look at, but you can use a C-style cast to do it, or `reinterpret_cast` as mentioned in the other answer.

If you want to learn the true types behind these Microsoft type names, you can check out  [their documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

A `HANDLE` on Windows is a void pointer.
To make an `int` (`unsigned long` etc.) out of it, you cannot use `static_cast`,
you´ll need an `reinterpret_cast`.

But, any int type is neither hexadecimal nor decimal, just a number
which can be expressed in both ways...

Answer (score 1):

HANDLE is basically void * i.e. a pointer type you may convert HANDLE to void * then to int, if you so desire